# Why base_url function returns the ipv6 address of my PC

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an application with codeigniter 3.0.3. After configuring and installing the template, I notice that the base_url () function instead of returning the address to the root of my PC returns the ipv6 address instead.The version of wampserver used is 3.0.6

echo base_url ('style.css') => 
Please help.

Comment: echo base_url('style.css');  => http://[fe80::74eb:19c9:79af:d059]/style.css

Comment: edit your question with this content instead of commenting to yourself... it's better than "Please help" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't actually set your `$config['base_url']`, which you are required to do.

Also, 3.0.3 is a pretty old version by now, you should be upgrading to the latest - 3.1.3 at the time I'm writing this.

Comment: Sorry it is rather the 3.1.3.
When I configure $ config ['base_url'] = 'http: // localhost / project', style sheets load but not fonts; It displays at the level of the "blocked by CORS policy: No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: That's a completely separate issue.